# ie doesn't pick up ng-model change angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ngmodel

I've asked this question before but still had no luck. I have a simple text input with a model attached like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testingInput"/>
<a ng-click="pushValue(testingInput)" class="button">Submit value</a>

$scope.testingInput = 0;
        $scope.pushValue = function(val){
           console.log(val);
           console.log($scope.testingInput);
        }
```

The aim is that 0 is first presented inside the input box - then the user can change it. When the ng-click is fired, it should come back with the new value that the user inputs. However on IE 8 and 9, it keeps logging the original value of 0.

Is there a compatibility hack I should be using with older IE browsers or should this just work as normal?

I'm using angular 1.2.28 if that helps at all.

Comment: Where and when is the ng-click event fired? It seems we are missing some code. :)

Comment: @saeraphin Woops, I've added in the button html now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you will experience problems when using `console.log()` within your angular controllers when using IE8, have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240896/angularjs-ie-8-support). Try the angular $log service.